# Hiding the splash screen of another process with a custom splash screen does not work with Qt::WindowsStaysOnTopHint

Tags: c++, qt, splash-screen

I am trying to start a process with Qt which shows its own splash screen. I want to place my own splash screen over the splash screen of this process (this process has nothing to do with Qt, it is a game!) since I cannot modify the process itself. This should hide the splash screen of the process and show mine instead. Therefore I am using the flag Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint. Most of the times it works but sometimes I can still see the splash screen of the process over my own splash screen. Is there a way to make really sure that no other window is over my splash screen except it is the full screen version of my process? Can I catch the window handle of the process somehow and check when it becomes full screen or is there a better flag?

The process starts shows a splash screen and then becomes a full screen game. Of course I do not want to overlay my splash screen this full screen game, only its splash screen at the beginning.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QSplashScreen>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // This is a modified game which has a splash screen I want to hide. I still show the copyright stuff in the picture ...
    const QString program = "../TPoF.exe";
    QStringList arguments;
    // This is my custom splash screen picture with an different logo thatn the one of the original game but still has the copyright remarks (Everybody knows that this is a modification anyway)
    QPixmap pixmap(":/cropped-dmdf-big.jpg");
    // The flag should make the splash screen overlay the existing one but does not always work.
    QSplashScreen splash(pixmap, Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    splash.showMessage(QObject::tr("Copyright 2003 Blizzard Entertainment. All rights reserved. (Warcraft III: The Frozen Throne)"), Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignBottom, QColor(0xFFCC00));
    splash.show();
    app.processEvents();

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(&app);
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);

    // Since I don't know how long the original splash screen stays there, I just wait until the whole process has finished. This is not a problem since the game is started in full screen.
    myProcess->waitForFinished();

    splash.close();

    return 0;
    //return app.exec();
}
```

**edit:**
Apparently some people don't get the question so I will add this:
It is a modification of a game and the game shows a logo by default. When the user starts my modification he will think that he starts the normal game and not my modification! Therefore I added a custom splash screen to inform him from the start that he is running the modification. Besides the original logo does not match my modification. Of course I can still add the copyrights text etc. but that is not part of the question since I know how to do this with QSplashScreen. The question is how to show a splash screen/QWidget really on top of ALL other windows since Qt::WindowsStaysOnTopHint does not always work.

**edit2:**
The original game is Warcraft III: The Frozen Throne. The original splash screen looks similar to this but with a copyright disclaimer and without the Blizzard logo at the top right corner: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/87/Warcraftiii-frozen-throne-boxcover.jpg

I've added the text in the code now that everyone sees I am keeping it.
If this is allowed or not I am not sure but you would have to have Warcraft III: The Frozen Throne installed anyway and played the original game.

The modification can be found here: http://www.moddb.com/mods/warcraft-iii-the-power-of-fire

My splash screen picture looks like this:
[image]

Of course the yellow text is added when it pops up.

Since I am not hiding the original game nor the original copyrights text etc. you can hardly say it is illegal. There's a bunch of modifications on the ModDB which alter graphics/logos etc. of the game and which can only be used with the original game. So you still have to buy the game .... I am not even modifying the game. Even if you think it is allowed please discuss the original technical question if you write something. It is a technical problem that another process's splash screen is on the top of all other windows.

Comment: Are you trying to hide somebodies copyright message? Or is it just a little plagiarism going on?

Comment: Please read my answer to Nathaniel. Obvisiouly you didnt get it. Its not about hiding the copyright of the program. It is about hiding the logo to show the logo of my game modification. Of course I can also add any copyright text but everyone knows it is a modification of that particular game....

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to consider here - the license of the product you are trying to modify and the means this product provides for modifying its contents. These govern the ways a third party can interact (code-wise) with the given product.

**A splash screen is a part of the application** whether you like it or not. In your question you have clearly stated that

> I cannot modify the process itself

What this means is that you don't have access to its source code (and even if you did the license kicks in and you have to consider what you can do with that source code) and the application itself clearly doesn't provide the means for a third party to modify its contents (for example some game developers allow mods for their games and thus they also offer the infrastructure for it).

Even with the best of intentions what you are attempting is a breach of a bunch of copyright laws. Also you might want to think about the modifications you are doing since from the looks of it the developer clearly doesn't want a third party to add anything on top of the original. If I'm wrong, then you should get in direct contact with the people behind it and clear things out. Even if modifications are allowed that might not be the case for specific parts of the game (such as the splash screen).

Last but not least I would advise you to post information about the application you want to modify (game or whatever) including its license. This will prevent people from thinking that you want to do something illegal (and believe me when I tell you that reading your post points in that direction).

Comment: I've added all the information. I don't think it is illegal since I am not modifying the application and somebody who uses the modification still has to have the original game which he has bought at some time and agreed to the license etc.

Comment: You are missing the point here - hiding something that is clearly there to be shown is modification of the way the application is supposed to work and thus an indirect modification of the application itself. As for the "has to have the original game" - sure but the game has license and that license applies **only to the game and all its assets**. Agreeing to the license of the game doesn't mean a thing when it comes to your modifications. The only thing in that license that matters is "Can a third party modify the product and if yes, then which parts of it?".